# Why won't my mod_rewrite work for HTTPS like HTTP

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, https

I'm sorry for yet another of these posts, but from what I can tell, my question is different than the prevailing http -> https redirects out there.

I want to

```
      redirect all http://www.mydomain.com traffic to https://www.mydomain.com/wiki
```

AND

```
      redirect https://www.mydomain.com   to   https://www.mydomain.com/wiki
```

Notice the https in my first redirect goal.

For the first redirect, I am able to accomplish this by putting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wiki [R,L]
```

In my httpd.conf file and restarting.

I thought this would also work for my https:// attempts. Notice, I am not including

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`

or anything like that. Yet, still https://www.mydomain.com sends me to my index.html file in my server root.

If I try to put the above Rewrite directives in my httpd-ssl.conf file and restart the server then I get infinite redirects.

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** For what its worth, /wiki is an alias to /home/Users/myusername/www/wiki (the absolute path to wiki)

**UPDATE**

Rehash as to what I've tried so far:

**Attempt 1:**

In httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wiki [R,L]
```

In httpd-ssl.conf:

Nothing Rewrite related

**Result 1:**

Redirects all http traffic to https://www.mydomain.com/wiki
Does nothing for https://www.mydomain.com

**Attempt 2:**

In httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wiki [R,L]
```

In httpd-ssl.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wiki [R,L]
```

**Result 2:**

Infinite redirects.

**Attempt 3:**

In httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule !^wiki https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wiki [R,L]
```

In httpd-ssl.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule !^wiki https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wiki [R,L]
```

**Result 3:**

Infinite redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that might not be the most robust but it works for me.

In my httpd-ssl.conf file, under the VirtualHost container, I set the DocumentRoot to point to the directory that I've been trying to redirect to.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "path on my HD where I wanted to redirect all along"
ServerName    All the usual stuff...
...
```

This takes care of "redirects" (not really redirects anymore) for https transactions

For http (non-ssl) I placed in httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wiki [R,L]
```

That seemed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule will match every request (even `/wiki`). Try to exclude that:

```
RewriteRule !^wiki https://%{HTTP_HOST}/wiki [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The infinite redirects are coming from the fact that the rule matches both the first client request (eg. http://...) and from any subsequent request.

You would do better to use a rewrite rule which excludes the wiki path from the match e.g.

```
RewriteRule !^wiki https://%{HTTP_HOST}/wiki [R,L]
```

or you might get better performance from a RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wiki
```

before your existing rule. This will make it easier to add more complex patterns that you currently have in your example (should you need to later in your project).

Comment: Can you clarify? What should I place in my httpd.conf and what in my httpd-ssl.conf ?

Comment: It all depends on your distribution. However, in this case you can just keep the whole lot in your httpd.conf file. It would also work in an .htaccess file, as long as the (virtual) server setup had AllowOverrides on for the DocumentRoot directory.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? Check out my attempt 3. I don't think this is working.

Comment: Which distro are you using? What do you have in the wiki folder (is the app there doing anything with redirects?